# Access violation setting web service element value in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, access-violation

I am trying to set the value of vRequest.odfl4Me.user in the code below.  When I run it I get an Access Violation Write error when it tries to execute that line.  I think it is because user is a property of the object ofodfl4me which is an object of bolRequest.  I assume I am not creating it correctly. Thank you in advance.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  WS: ODPickup_v2_0;
  vRequest: bolRequest;
  vResponse: bolResponse;
begin
  WS := ODPickup.GetODPickup_v2_0();
  vRequest := bolRequest.Create;
  vResponse:= bolResponse.Create;
  try
    vRequest.odfl4Me.user := 'test';    // Access violation on this line
    vResponse := WS.getBillOfLading(vRequest);
    ShowMessage(vResponse.bolReturn.odflTrackingNumber);
  finally
    WS := nil;
    vResponse.Free;
    vRequest.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The ODPickup.pas code generated by the WSDL import wizard is here:

```
unit ODPickup;

interface
uses InvokeRegistry, SOAPHTTPClient, Types, XSBuiltIns;

const
  IS_OPTN = $0001;
  IS_UNBD = $0002;
  IS_NLBL = $0004;
  IS_UNQL = $0008;
  IS_REF  = $0080;

type
  Accessorial          = class;                 { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[GblCplx] }
  Customer             = class;                 { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[GblCplx] }
  CodDetail            = class;                 { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[GblCplx] }
  ShipmentRefId        = class;                 { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[GblCplx] }
  Consignee            = class;                 { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[GblCplx] }
  Odfl4Me              = class;                 { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[GblCplx] }
  pickupResponse       = class;                 { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[Lit][GblElm] }
  pickupRequest        = class;                 { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[Lit][GblElm] }
  bolResponse          = class;                 { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[Lit][GblElm] }
  bolRequest           = class;                 { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[Lit][GblElm] }
  BolDetail            = class;                 { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[GblCplx] }
  Commodity            = class;                 { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[GblCplx] }
  BolResult            = class;                 { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[GblCplx] }
  ConsigneeResult      = class;                 { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[GblCplx] }


  Accessorial = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fcode: string;
    Fvalue: string;
  published
    property code:  string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fcode write Fcode;
    property value: string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fvalue write Fvalue;
  end;


  Customer = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FaccountNumber: string;
    FcompanyName: string;
    FaddressLine1: string;
    FaddressLine2: string;
    Fcity: string;
    FstateProvince: string;
    FpostalCode: string;
    Fcountry: string;
    FphoneAreaCode: string;
    FphoneNumber: string;
    FphoneExt: string;
    FfaxAreaCode: string;
    FfaxNumber: string;
    Fattention: string;
    FcontactFName: string;
    FcontactLName: string;
    Femail: string;
    Fcomments: string;
  published
    property accountNumber: string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FaccountNumber write FaccountNumber;
    property companyName:   string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FcompanyName write FcompanyName;
    property addressLine1:  string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FaddressLine1 write FaddressLine1;
    property addressLine2:  string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FaddressLine2 write FaddressLine2;
    property city:          string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fcity write Fcity;
    property stateProvince: string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FstateProvince write FstateProvince;
    property postalCode:    string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FpostalCode write FpostalCode;
    property country:       string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fcountry write Fcountry;
    property phoneAreaCode: string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FphoneAreaCode write FphoneAreaCode;
    property phoneNumber:   string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FphoneNumber write FphoneNumber;
    property phoneExt:      string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FphoneExt write FphoneExt;
    property faxAreaCode:   string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FfaxAreaCode write FfaxAreaCode;
    property faxNumber:     string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FfaxNumber write FfaxNumber;
    property attention:     string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fattention write Fattention;
    property contactFName:  string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FcontactFName write FcontactFName;
    property contactLName:  string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FcontactLName write FcontactLName;
    property email:         string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Femail write Femail;
    property comments:      string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fcomments write Fcomments;
  end;


  CodDetail = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Famount: string;
    FpaymentMethod: string;
    FcodFee: string;
    FremitTo: string;
    FaddressLine1: string;
    FaddressLine2: string;
    Fcity: string;
    FstateProvince: string;
    FpostalCode: string;
    Fcountry: string;
    Fattention: string;
  published
    property amount:        string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Famount write Famount;
    property paymentMethod: string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FpaymentMethod write FpaymentMethod;
    property codFee:        string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FcodFee write FcodFee;
    property remitTo:       string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FremitTo write FremitTo;
    property addressLine1:  string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FaddressLine1 write FaddressLine1;
    property addressLine2:  string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FaddressLine2 write FaddressLine2;
    property city:          string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fcity write Fcity;
    property stateProvince: string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FstateProvince write FstateProvince;
    property postalCode:    string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FpostalCode write FpostalCode;
    property country:       string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fcountry write Fcountry;
    property attention:     string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fattention write Fattention;
  end;


  ShipmentRefId = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FreferenceId: string;
    FidQualifier: string;
    FpoDepartment: string;
  published
    property referenceId:  string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FreferenceId write FreferenceId;
    property idQualifier:  string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FidQualifier write FidQualifier;
    property poDepartment: string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FpoDepartment write FpoDepartment;
  end;


  Consignee = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FconsigneeDetail: Customer;
    FshipmentDetail: Commodity;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property consigneeDetail: Customer   Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FconsigneeDetail write FconsigneeDetail;
    property shipmentDetail:  Commodity  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FshipmentDetail write FshipmentDetail;
  end;

  Odfl4Me = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fuser: string;
    Fpassword: string;
  published
    property user:     string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fuser write Fuser;
    property password: string  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fpassword write Fpassword;
  end;


  bolResponse = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FbolReturn: BolResult;
  public
    constructor Create; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property bolReturn: BolResult  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FbolReturn write FbolReturn;
  end;


 bolRequest = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fodfl4Me: Odfl4Me;
    FbolDetail: BolDetail;
  public
    constructor Create; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property odfl4Me:   Odfl4Me    Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fodfl4Me write Fodfl4Me;
    property bolDetail: BolDetail  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FbolDetail write FbolDetail;
  end;

  Array_Of_Accessorial = array of Accessorial;   { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[GblUbnd] }
  Array_Of_Commodity = array of Commodity;      { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[GblUbnd] }


  BolDetail = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FcontactName: string;
    FcontactPhoneAreaCode: string;
    FcontactPhoneNumber: string;
    FcontactPhoneExt: string;
    FpickupDate: string;
    FpickupTime: string;
    FpickupTimeAMPM: string;
    FdockCloseTime: string;
    FdockCloseAMPM: string;
    FcallForAppointment: Boolean;
    FpaymentType: string;
    FbolNumber: string;
    FreferenceNumber: string;
    FrequestGuaranteedRate: Boolean;
    FpickupInstruction: string;
    FbolComments: string;
    Fshipper: Customer;
    Fconsignee: Customer;
    FbillTo: Customer;
    FcodDetails: CodDetail;
    Faccessorials: Array_Of_Accessorial;
    Faccessorials_Specified: boolean;
    FhandlingUnits: string;
    Fcommodities: Array_Of_Commodity;
    Fcommodities_Specified: boolean;
    FhazMatContactName: string;
    FhazMatContactPhone: string;
    FrateReferenceNumber: string;
    FemailDeliveryConfirm: string;
    FemailBol: string;
    FtestFlag: Boolean;
    procedure Setaccessorials(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_Accessorial: Array_Of_Accessorial);
    function  accessorials_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setcommodities(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_Commodity: Array_Of_Commodity);
    function  commodities_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property contactName:           string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FcontactName write FcontactName;
    property contactPhoneAreaCode:  string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FcontactPhoneAreaCode write FcontactPhoneAreaCode;
    property contactPhoneNumber:    string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FcontactPhoneNumber write FcontactPhoneNumber;
    property contactPhoneExt:       string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FcontactPhoneExt write FcontactPhoneExt;
    property pickupDate:            string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FpickupDate write FpickupDate;
    property pickupTime:            string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FpickupTime write FpickupTime;
    property pickupTimeAMPM:        string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FpickupTimeAMPM write FpickupTimeAMPM;
    property dockCloseTime:         string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FdockCloseTime write FdockCloseTime;
    property dockCloseAMPM:         string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FdockCloseAMPM write FdockCloseAMPM;
    property callForAppointment:    Boolean               Index (IS_UNQL) read FcallForAppointment write FcallForAppointment;
    property paymentType:           string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FpaymentType write FpaymentType;
    property bolNumber:             string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FbolNumber write FbolNumber;
    property referenceNumber:       string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FreferenceNumber write FreferenceNumber;
    property requestGuaranteedRate: Boolean               Index (IS_UNQL) read FrequestGuaranteedRate write FrequestGuaranteedRate;
    property pickupInstruction:     string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FpickupInstruction write FpickupInstruction;
    property bolComments:           string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FbolComments write FbolComments;
    property shipper:               Customer              Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fshipper write Fshipper;
    property consignee:             Customer              Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fconsignee write Fconsignee;
    property billTo:                Customer              Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FbillTo write FbillTo;
    property codDetails:            CodDetail             Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FcodDetails write FcodDetails;
    property accessorials:          Array_Of_Accessorial  Index (IS_OPTN or IS_UNBD or IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Faccessorials write Setaccessorials stored accessorials_Specified;
    property handlingUnits:         string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FhandlingUnits write FhandlingUnits;
    property commodities:           Array_Of_Commodity    Index (IS_OPTN or IS_UNBD or IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fcommodities write Setcommodities stored commodities_Specified;
    property hazMatContactName:     string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FhazMatContactName write FhazMatContactName;
    property hazMatContactPhone:    string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FhazMatContactPhone write FhazMatContactPhone;
    property rateReferenceNumber:   string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FrateReferenceNumber write FrateReferenceNumber;
    property emailDeliveryConfirm:  string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FemailDeliveryConfirm write FemailDeliveryConfirm;
    property emailBol:              string                Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FemailBol write FemailBol;
    property testFlag:              Boolean               Index (IS_UNQL) read FtestFlag write FtestFlag;
  end;

  Array_Of_ShipmentRefId = array of ShipmentRefId;   { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[GblUbnd] }


  Commodity = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fpieces: string;
    FunitType: string;
    Fweight: string;
    Fhazmat: Boolean;
    Ffreezable: Boolean;
    FlongDescription: string;
    FshortDescription: string;
    FshipmentRefIds: Array_Of_ShipmentRefId;
    FshipmentRefIds_Specified: boolean;
    FnmfcCode: string;
    FnmfcSubCode: string;
    FnmfcClass: string;
    procedure SetshipmentRefIds(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_ShipmentRefId: Array_Of_ShipmentRefId);
    function  shipmentRefIds_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property pieces:           string                  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fpieces write Fpieces;
    property unitType:         string                  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FunitType write FunitType;
    property weight:           string                  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read Fweight write Fweight;
    property hazmat:           Boolean                 Index (IS_UNQL) read Fhazmat write Fhazmat;
    property freezable:        Boolean                 Index (IS_UNQL) read Ffreezable write Ffreezable;
    property longDescription:  string                  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FlongDescription write FlongDescription;
    property shortDescription: string                  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FshortDescription write FshortDescription;
    property shipmentRefIds:   Array_Of_ShipmentRefId  Index (IS_OPTN or IS_UNBD or IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FshipmentRefIds write SetshipmentRefIds stored shipmentRefIds_Specified;
    property nmfcCode:         string                  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FnmfcCode write FnmfcCode;
    property nmfcSubCode:      string                  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FnmfcSubCode write FnmfcSubCode;
    property nmfcClass:        string                  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FnmfcClass write FnmfcClass;
  end;

  Array_Of_string = array of string;            { "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[GblUbnd] }


  BolResult = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FodflTrackingNumber: string;
    FerrorMessages: Array_Of_string;
    FerrorMessages_Specified: boolean;
    procedure SeterrorMessages(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_string: Array_Of_string);
    function  errorMessages_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  published
    property odflTrackingNumber: string           Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FodflTrackingNumber write FodflTrackingNumber;
    property errorMessages:      Array_Of_string  Index (IS_OPTN or IS_UNBD or IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FerrorMessages write SeterrorMessages stored errorMessages_Specified;
  end;



  ConsigneeResult = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FsequenceNumber: string;
    FodflTrackingNumber: string;
    FerrorMessages: Array_Of_string;
    FerrorMessages_Specified: boolean;
    procedure SeterrorMessages(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_string: Array_Of_string);
    function  errorMessages_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  published
    property sequenceNumber:     string           Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FsequenceNumber write FsequenceNumber;
    property odflTrackingNumber: string           Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FodflTrackingNumber write FodflTrackingNumber;
    property errorMessages:      Array_Of_string  Index (IS_OPTN or IS_UNBD or IS_UNQL) read FerrorMessages write SeterrorMessages stored errorMessages_Specified;
  end;

  Array_Of_Consignee = array of Consignee;      { "http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0"[GblUbnd] }



  ODPickup_v2_0 = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{0E054705-9C47-AE2E-0D6E-8032B5475822}']

    // Cannot unwrap: 
    //     - Input element wrapper name does not match operation's name
    function  getBillOfLading(const parameters: bolRequest): bolResponse; stdcall;
  end;

function GetODPickup_v2_0(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil): ODPickup_v2_0;


implementation
  uses SysUtils;

function GetODPickup_v2_0(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): ODPickup_v2_0;
const
  defWSDL = 'https://www.odfl.com/wsPickup_v2/services/ODPickup?wsdl';
  defURL  = 'https://www.odfl.com:443/wsPickup_v2/services/ODPickup';
  defSvc  = 'ODPickup_v2_0';
  defPrt  = 'ODPickup';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as ODPickup_v2_0);
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;


destructor Consignee.Destroy;
begin
  SysUtils.FreeAndNil(FconsigneeDetail);
  SysUtils.FreeAndNil(FshipmentDetail);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

constructor bolResponse.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FSerializationOptions := [xoLiteralParam];
end;

destructor bolResponse.Destroy;
begin
  SysUtils.FreeAndNil(FbolReturn);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

constructor bolRequest.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FSerializationOptions := [xoLiteralParam];
end;

destructor bolRequest.Destroy;
begin
  SysUtils.FreeAndNil(Fodfl4Me);
  SysUtils.FreeAndNil(FbolDetail);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

destructor BolDetail.Destroy;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to System.Length(Faccessorials)-1 do
    SysUtils.FreeAndNil(Faccessorials[I]);
  System.SetLength(Faccessorials, 0);
  for I := 0 to System.Length(Fcommodities)-1 do
    SysUtils.FreeAndNil(Fcommodities[I]);
  System.SetLength(Fcommodities, 0);
  SysUtils.FreeAndNil(Fshipper);
  SysUtils.FreeAndNil(Fconsignee);
  SysUtils.FreeAndNil(FbillTo);
  SysUtils.FreeAndNil(FcodDetails);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure BolDetail.Setaccessorials(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_Accessorial: Array_Of_Accessorial);
begin
  Faccessorials := AArray_Of_Accessorial;
  Faccessorials_Specified := True;
end;

function BolDetail.accessorials_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := Faccessorials_Specified;
end;

procedure BolDetail.Setcommodities(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_Commodity: Array_Of_Commodity);
begin
  Fcommodities := AArray_Of_Commodity;
  Fcommodities_Specified := True;
end;

function BolDetail.commodities_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := Fcommodities_Specified;
end;

destructor Commodity.Destroy;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to System.Length(FshipmentRefIds)-1 do
    SysUtils.FreeAndNil(FshipmentRefIds[I]);
  System.SetLength(FshipmentRefIds, 0);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure Commodity.SetshipmentRefIds(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_ShipmentRefId: Array_Of_ShipmentRefId);
begin
  FshipmentRefIds := AArray_Of_ShipmentRefId;
  FshipmentRefIds_Specified := True;
end;

function Commodity.shipmentRefIds_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := FshipmentRefIds_Specified;
end;

procedure BolResult.SeterrorMessages(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_string: Array_Of_string);
begin
  FerrorMessages := AArray_Of_string;
  FerrorMessages_Specified := True;
end;

function BolResult.errorMessages_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := FerrorMessages_Specified;
end;

procedure ConsigneeResult.SeterrorMessages(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_string: Array_Of_string);
begin
  FerrorMessages := AArray_Of_string;
  FerrorMessages_Specified := True;
end;

function ConsigneeResult.errorMessages_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := FerrorMessages_Specified;
end;


initialization
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(ODPickup_v2_0), 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2', 'UTF-8');
  InvRegistry.RegisterDefaultSOAPAction(TypeInfo(ODPickup_v2_0), '');
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(ODPickup_v2_0), ioDocument);
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(ODPickup_v2_0), ioLiteral);
  InvRegistry.RegisterExternalParamName(TypeInfo(ODPickup_v2_0), 'getBillOfLading', 'parameters1', 'parameters');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(Accessorial, 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0', 'Accessorial');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(Customer, 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0', 'Customer');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(CodDetail, 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0', 'CodDetail');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(ShipmentRefId, 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0', 'ShipmentRefId');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(Consignee, 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0', 'Consignee');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(Odfl4Me, 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0', 'Odfl4Me');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(bolResponse, 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0', 'bolResponse');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterSerializeOptions(bolResponse, [xoLiteralParam]);
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(bolRequest, 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0', 'bolRequest');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterSerializeOptions(bolRequest, [xoLiteralParam]);
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(Array_Of_Accessorial), 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0', 'Array_Of_Accessorial');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(Array_Of_Commodity), 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0', 'Array_Of_Commodity');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(BolDetail, 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0', 'BolDetail');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(Array_Of_ShipmentRefId), 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0', 'Array_Of_ShipmentRefId');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(Commodity, 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0', 'Commodity');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(Array_Of_string), 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', 'Array_Of_string');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(BolResult, 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0', 'BolResult');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(ConsigneeResult, 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0', 'ConsigneeResult');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(Array_Of_Consignee), 'http://odfl.com/ws/ODPickup-v2.0', 'Array_Of_Consignee');
end.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone else, I solved it.  Had to create an array of objects, set the length, then vRequest.bolDetail.commodities = myItemArray;

Comment: This is unrelated to the question asked and completely fails to answer that question. My answer is accurate. The fact that there was more work required to make the rest of your program work is irrelevant. Please read the question again. It asks about an AV at a specific line of code. Nothing at all to do with the text here.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the generated import unit, and assuming the importer did its job correctly, it is your responsibility to create and assign `vRequest.odfl4Me`.

```
vRequest.odfl4Me := Odfl4Me.Create;
```

You must do this before assigning the properties of `odfl4Me`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Couldn't see the forest for the trees I guess.